# Translation as product of reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

I am facing the following problem, given the translation in the euclidean affine space of dimension 4

$
\tau_v=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{3}{2} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$

decompose it as a product of reflections. I have tried to follow this
[entry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139351/translation-as-a-product-of-two-reflection) where this precise problem is treated but I have doubts about how to choose the planes of the reflections.

Comment: Given the information in the linked solution, what can you say about the two reflecting planes?

Comment: @amd They are ortogonal with respecto to $v$ and differ by $v/2$. But i fail at deriving such planes from the matrix.

Comment: Start by determining $v$. You should be able to do this by inspection.

Comment: @amd Well, $v$ is $(0, \frac{3}{2}, 0)$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Now you just need to planes orthogonal to this vector and separated by a distance of $3/4$. Really, you only need one: once you’ve constructed the first reflection, you can compute the other from it and $\tau_v$. There’s an obvious simple choice for the first plane.

Comment: @amd So it would be enough to find a symmetry, for example, $
s_1 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$ the symmetry with respecto to $e_1, e_3$, and get $s_2$ as $\tau_v * s_1$?

Comment: Yes, that’s the simplest way to go, I think. You should be able to write up an answer to this question yourself now.